# Make Heatmap Look More Professional in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I can build very basic plots in R, but I'm trying to make my heatmap look more professional and I'm not sure how to do it. I have a data frame `df` of 11 observations of 11 variables:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(`0` = c(6.08, 7.91, 5.14, 2.23, 0.72, 0.19, 0.04, 
0.01, 0, 0, 0), `1` = c(9.12, 11.86, 7.71, 3.34, 1.09, 0.28, 
0.06, 0.01, 0, 0, 0), `2` = c(6.84, 8.89, 5.78, 2.5, 0.81, 0.21, 
0.05, 0.01, 0, 0, 0), `3` = c(3.42, 4.45, 2.89, 1.25, 0.41, 0.11, 
0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0), `4` = c(1.28, 1.67, 1.08, 0.47, 0.15, 0.04, 
0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0), `5` = c(0.38, 0.5, 0.33, 0.14, 0.05, 0.01, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `6` = c(0.1, 0.13, 0.08, 0.04, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), `7` = c(0.02, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), `8` = c(0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `9` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `10+` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0)), row.names = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10+"), class = "data.frame")
```

So I transform `df` into a matrix to get a heatmap:

```
heatmap(data.matrix(df), Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, col = heat.colors(256), scale="column", margins=c(5,10))
```

This is what the plot looks like:

[image]

I'm not sure how to:

1. Change the location of the keys for the row and columns. I want them both to start from 0 in the top left corner, and both row and column to continue ascending until 10+
2. I'd also like more granularity in the colour. Right now you can't event tell the difference in values by looking at the colour...

Is `heatmap` from base R even the right library for this? I looked up a few examples and I wasn't sure if there's a better library to achieve what I want.

Comment: you might find it easier working with `ggplot`. You can use `geom_raster` to make heatmaps. Data need to be in long format (use `pivot_longer()`). Would help if you posted some data (with `dput(df)`)

Comment: Read about [ComplexHeatmap](https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several libraries that offer heatmap functionalities. IMO base `heatmap` and `gplots::heatmap.2` did not age well and are not the best options anymore. 3 good possibilities are with `ggplot2::geom_tile`, `pheatmap` and `ComplexHeatmap`.

## Example data

Let's assume we have a matrix

```
dta <- matrix(rnorm(25), nrow=5)
rownames(dta) <- letters[1:5]
colnames(dta) <- LETTERS[1:5]
```

## ggplot2::geom_tile

The ggplot2 version requires your data to be a tidy dataframe, so we can transform our matrix with `tidyr::pivot_longer()`.

```
dta %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "myrows") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -myrows, names_to = "mycols", values_to = "level") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_tile(aes(x=myrows, y=mycols, fill = level))
```

## pheatmap

The `pheatmap` package is quite good at generating modern heatmaps. It takes a matrix as input. It can cluster the rows and columns and make a dendrogram, which is often a desired feature. It can also scale rows and columns (effectively plotting a Z-score).

```
pheatmap::pheatmap(dta,
                   scale = "none",
                   cluster_rows = FALSE,
                   cluster_cols = FALSE)
```

Note that the positions of rows and columns are not the same as with `ggplot`. You can look at the options that allow some useful customization. For example, if our rows have classes defined elsewhere.

```
ann_df <- data.frame(row.names = rownames(dta),
                     classification = rep(c("first", "second"), times = c(2,3)))
pheatmap::pheatmap(dta,
                   scale = "none",
                   cluster_rows = FALSE,
                   cluster_cols = FALSE,
                   annotation_row = ann_df,
                   gaps_row = c(2))
```

## Color scale

One of the big aspects that make your heatmap look professional is the color scale. On ggplot, you should check out `scale_fill_gradient2()`.

On pheatmap, you can try these settings for `color` as a starting point (see the documentation of these functions):

```
color = scales::div_gradient_pal(low = "navy",
  mid = "green",
  high="yellow")(seq(0,1,
    length.out = max(dta))),

color = colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 9,
      name = "Blues"))(max(dta)),

color = viridisLite::plasma(max(dta)),
```

## ComplexHeatmap

Finally, a package that has gained success recently is `ComplexHeatmap`. It is based on `pheatmap` but offers many additional options. See [the link](https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/) in zx8754's comment for a detailed book full of examples.

Comment: Hi @AlexLok this is really good thanks, just what I needed! Just one last question, I have gone with ggplot2::geom_tile but the issue is that my rows and columns are in order of (0,1,10 or more,2...) instead of (0,1,2,...10 or more). How do I resolve this?

Comment: Here your axes labels are character vectors (and not numeric, since "10+" can't be numeric), they will be in alphabetical order. To force the order, you can convert them to a factor, and set the levels in the right order. Something like: `df$x <- factor(df$x, levels=c("0","1", ... "9", "10+"))` and same for the columns.